# How to pass URL from ListView item to web browser URL

Tags: c#, uwp

How can the URL data within a list view item be passed to a web browser to open? My current code isn't working for some reason.

> The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

**page class**

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public List<ListItem> listItemCompanies;

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            listItemCompanies = ItemManager.GetListItems();
        }

        private async void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();

            foreach (var item in e.AddedItems)
            {
                showWebsite();
            }
        }

        private async void showWebsite()
        {
            var title = item as ListItem;

            var uriWeb = new Uri(title.CompanyURL);
            var uriSuccess = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriWeb);
        }
    }
}
```

**list item class**

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class ListItem
    {
        public string CompanyTitle { get; set; }
        public string CompanyURL { get; set; }
    }

    public class ItemManager
    {
        public static List<ListItem> GetListItems()
        {    
            var items = new List<ListItem>
            {
                new ListItem { CompanyTitle = "Apple", CompanyURL = "www.apple.com" },
                new ListItem { CompanyTitle = "Google", CompanyURL = "www.google.com" },
                new ListItem { CompanyTitle = "Microsoft", CompanyURL = "www.microsoft.com" }
            };

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to build a table.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36475679/dynamically-create-html-table-in-c-sharp

Comment: Why? Just to do something this simple.

Comment: What is simple?  A ListItem is an object and what are you using to view the object?  You need a method to view the data on a webpage.

Comment: Correct, which I created in `showWebsite` but obviously the 'title' variable has incorrect code. I'm not looking to draw a table.

Comment: From : var title = item as ListItem; To : var title = ItemManager.GerListItens()[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the document of [Uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/uri-schemes#common-features-of-the-uri-schemes), there are essentially three components to a URI, the first part is scheme. Taking the web URL as an example, the scheme part is "http://". So when you try to create a Uri class, you also need to pass the "http://" instead of only "www.apple.com". In addition, when the **ListView_SelectionChanged** event is triggered, you can call the **SelectedItem** property of ListView to get the model you current click. For example:

```
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    object item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
    showWebsite(item);
}

private async void showWebsite(object item)
{
    var title = item as ListItem;

    var uriWeb = new Uri("http://" + title.CompanyURL);
    var uriSuccess = await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriWeb);
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to use ItemClick event, you need to set the IsItemClickEnabled of ListView as True.

.xaml:

```
<ListView ... IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick">
    ......
</ListView>
```

.cs:

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    object item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem;
    showWebsite(item);
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to use the `SelectionChanged` event handler rather than the `ItemClick` event handler?

Comment: These two events are both OK, since at first you showed the SelectionChanged above, I directly used this event to demonstrate. If you want to use ItemClick event, you can check my answer which is updated.